# NodeJS just crashes without any information

Tags: node.js

I am trying to deploy a meteor (nodeJS) app on a Virtual Server.

My Problem:

I cannot start `forever` - I thought. Then I tried to start the app as described in the manual: `node main.js` just error code -1.

Then I tried to check wich Node version is installed `node -v` and I also get a return value of -1 and no more error message.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: are you able to reach to node cli? (by typing `node` on server terminal)

Comment: nope, just get -1 as bash return value.

Comment: are you sure, node is properly installed on your server?

Comment: It clearly is badly installed, and we cannot help you as we have no information.

Comment: are you able to execute `nodejs` at your shell prompt?

Answer (score 0):

A reinstallation of the nodejs packet (jap, the "node" packet is something different in ubuntu) helped